# Jobs Regarding Network Security

Tags: professional-education

I am new college graduate from India with no job experience. I have deep interest in Information Security and would like to a work for any good company related to the field. Since I don't have experience no one wants to give me a job. What should I do to get noticed, and a job, by a good company?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **Get a job in the IT industry** - any job. Work a help desk if you have to because that still counts as experience and experience is what employers really want to see on a resume. Get your foot in the door. I know a lot of people (myself included) who got to where they are because of entry level jobs and working hard to prove their worth.
2. **Get involved in the community** - The harsh reality is that your GPA from college doesn't mean anything in the real world. You'll learn ideal circumstances and great foundations, but there is a big difference to how things are done in the real world and how they are done in academia. Chatting in forums and discussion boards is a great way to expand your mind and learn about new technology and techniques.
3. **Network** - There is a popular saying in hiring that goes "It's not what you know, it's *who* you know. Nepotism is huge in the job market so get out there and meet people and prove your skills to them. You'll get to meet new people, get insight from their experiences and hopefully they'll give you a heads up on new job opportunities. Go to trade shows and local events to meet new people and discuss the industry with them.
4. **Look into industry certifications** - Employers like to see certifications (MCITP, MCSA, S+, CISSP, the list goes on and on). With your college education you've got a great foundation for getting these certifications. Spend some extra time and money and look into getting certified. You'll learn lots and you'll show employers you're dedicated to your craft.
5. **Volunteer** - Yes, not getting paid sucks, but you'll get experience and you'll likely get the tutelage from someone who's been in the industry for a while. Nobody is going to trust the security to a fresh grad with no real world experience (I'm sorry, but it's the truth), but you'll almost always find someone who's willing to take a volunteer. IT staff are overworked, and you may get stuck doing menial tasks but you'll still learn. If you do well you'll likely be considered if a paid job opens up too.

Comment: thanks a lot @DKNUCKLES....I want to do some certification but I have no money as they costlier in India specially...so any organization who provide these certifications less costly basis of performance and have values....

Comment: I understand that they are expensive to take. The good news is that companies will usually pay for employees to take these certifications as they benefit from you knowing more so if you get hired somewhere where you can use those skills, you should bring it up. I like to think of them as an investment in yourself - worth the money.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES-Can I get those company name so I can apply?

Comment: I would disagree with "*Employers like to see certifications*". The top candidates rarely (never?) have certifications because they don't have anything to prove; they understand the industry better than the people writing the certification tests. Companies who want the *top* employees tend to ignore certs. Certs help separate [mediocre](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2005/01/27.html) candidates from bad ones.